# Extract Month and Day in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I have the date in this format: 1347564203.713372

And need to end up with 2 variables, one that is the month from that date and another that is the day from that date.

How do I do this using Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

This should do:

```
var myDate = 1347564203.713372;
var d= new Date(myDate*1000);
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
```

Comment: Note that in the above, the time value `1347564203.713372` is treated as UTC, but `getMonth` and `getDate` will be based on the local timezone of the client. Someone in a timezone UTC+10hrs might see a different month and date to someone in UTC-6hrs.

Comment: @RobG: This is correct, but there is nothing about UTC in the original question.

Comment: Yes, so you can't assume one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Date object, use `setTime` to put your timestamp in there, then get the relevant parts:

```
var d = new Date(), t = 1347564203.713372;
d.setTime(t*1000); // JS uses timestamps in milliseconds
alert(d.getUTCDate());
alert(["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"][d.getUTCMonth()]);
```

Note use of `getUTC*` functions - this helps avoid timezone issues and DST.